# Smooth transition from image background to color background

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my first time seeking help for myself on this platform so I apologize if the solution I'm looking for is very easy, I am new to JS... I'm trying to find a way to smoothly transition from the current background image which is black and "white" -- lightest "shade" being #ccc, darkest being #000 -- to a solid #ccc background with the click of a button.

So essentially, I click a button and then the current background transforms into a solid gray background. I managed to do that but it's very abrupt.

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<body id="bd">
.
.
.
   <h2 class="test" onclick="backgroundToGray()" >test</h2>
   <script>
      function change(){
         document.getElementById("bd").style.background='#ccc';
      }
   </script>
.
.
.
</body>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    background: #ccc;
    background-image: url("background.png");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: You need to use transition property in your css. 

Transition: 1s will transition over a 1 second timeframe.

Comment: @liebestod Just adding a transition doesn't solve the problem of moving from background image to solid color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses a [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to fade the background image's opacity to zero, revealing a solid color background underneath.

Because there's no CSS property to set a background image's opacity, I'm using a `::before` [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) to hold the image and transitioning that entire element's opacity.

This introduces a couple of minor complications. See the code comments for details.

```js
function change(){
  // changed to classList.toggle to add/remove a classname
  // with each click.
  document.getElementById("bd").classList.toggle('grey');
}
```

```css
#bd {
    height: 90vh; /* just ensuring it occupies enough vertical space for the demo */
    background: #ccc; /* set the solid background color */
    position: relative; /* required for the ::before pseudo-element below to position properly */
}

#bd > * {
  position: relative; /* ensures the content appears on top of the ::before element instead of behind it */
}

#bd::before {
  content: ''; /* required for pseudo elements to render */
  
  /* position the element to cover the entire parent */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  /* set up your bg image here, just as you originally had on #bd */
  /* changed the image url to something that will render on stackoverflow */
  background-image: url("//placekitten.com/400/400");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
  /* initially fully opaque so the image is visible */
  opacity: 1;
  
  /* animate the opacity when it changes over 1 second */
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

#bd.grey::before {
  /* when the .grey class is present opacity switches to zero. */
  /* and because of the transition rule above the change is animated */
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- stripped to its bare minimum just for clarity. no important changes here. -->
<div id="bd">
   <h2 class="test" onclick="change()" >test</h2>      
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try something like this:

1. Remove 'html' from css selector
2. In your HTML file, adjust the change() function so onclick event will add a given class to the body
3. use this class in CSS and smoothly transition background color with [animation property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) and keyframes.

Below you will find my snippets for that:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('./background.png');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

body.animatedColorTransition {
  animation: color-transition 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes color-transition {
  from {
    background: #000;  /* shade of the background, you can read about linear-gradient */
  }
  to {
    background: #ccc; /* desired shade*/
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body id="bd">
    <h2 class="test" onclick="change()">test</h2>
    <script>
      function change() {
        document.getElementById('bd').classList.add('animatedColorTransition');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Good luck and tell me if it works for you!

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of transitioning the _background image_ to a solid color.